# How feasible is it for a construction company working 24/7 to superficially cover a (roughly) 2500x2500x500ft quarry and how long would it take?

Tags: engineering, construction, macroengineering

A construction company has an immense workforce and wants to superficially cover a quarry and retain use of the interior for further and later development. The budget and workforce is immense, with speed being the top priority. Modern construction equipment and methods are available.

Additional Clarification:
The quarry already exists with the supports necessary to prevent collapse and can be shallower, deeper, or smaller to meet the roofing needs (so long as it remains a plausible, former quarry). The purpose of the covering is to conceal the quarry or give the impression it was fully filled in.
It needs to withstand wind and rains (or at least divert rains into a single area below the roof); snow is not a concern. It must also withstand temperatures in the 40-90 range.
Further expansion need not be considered. It needs to bear nominal to moderate weight, in the very least, for dirt, and probably a small, light, cheaply-built, single-story apartment complex. The roof and dirt thereon will remain uninvestigated, but needs to bear a layer of dirt that will withstand basic scrutiny (2-5ft).
The roof can be supported by pillars and built in segments.
The secrecy of the area is being actively maintained, and as a result, it can be assumed that security, maintenance, etc are continuous and thorough.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is the purpose of the covering?  Prevent people falling in, prevent detection from the air, prevent detection from the ground, prevent people working inside getting wet?  What further and later development is being considered - further mining, repurpose into an artificial cave for an evil overlord...?  We can't answer without more of an idea of what you are asking?

Comment: Is the quarry already in place? What other works have been performed on that quarry in order to make it suitable to be covered by "a roof"? Any data on the roof profile (2500x2500 ft is an extremely large roof, I don't remember any close already created RL project)? What about weather load (snow/ice/rain, temp cycle), this alters durability requirements on the roof together with its support? Answers on these question could alter final time from about half a year to "not feasible"/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_River_Gorge_Bridge

Length 3,030 ft, width  69.3 ft. Build bunch of them near each other. The bridge was built in 3 years but your cover doesn't have to be as robust, so you could cut lots of corners. There would be some economy of scale. It would give you roof without relying on columns where you don't want them - assuming you want to dig deeper.

It made of steel elements made somewhere else and assembled/welded in place. Time table depends on how much money you can throw at it. I would say it can be done in a year.

If you want it faster, just make a big deal out of it, entire world is making steel beams for you and you flying in engineers from China on planes you rented from Delta Air Lines.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is possible with current methods. The largest Roof I could find was about 300 metres long, with the largest surface area I could find being 110,000 square meters. Your roof line is double that in length and quadruple that in surface area.

Presuming from the question that since you want to use the interior (I'm thinking like something from Diamonds are Forever with the Volcano base) that the roof has to be permanent and able to withstand a day-to-day weather and wear/tear. This means it can't be say a sheet of Fabric or similar and has to be a semi-rigid structure.

If you split it up into sections (rather than a single span) then maybe?

So, assuming you build from the ground up a complete interior, that's only 150 metres tall, which isn't super high and then had regularly supported roof spans, I think a project of this size would take several years to complete - no more than 5 (this is based on the time it took to build the Hoover Dam which is a bit taller - but also done in the 1930s).

In order to get maximal speed, you could pre-fab sections of the build offsite (as space within the quarry would limit the amount of work that could be done) - but with such a large project, delays could easily push the schedule out by months or even years (for example if there's a lot of rain that turns the base of the quarry into a swamp and requiring it to be drained before any building can be done.

Comment: I really appreciate the reply, thank you! the roof can be built in sections and be supported by the walls, pillars, and whatever other means necessary. The depth of the quarry can also be more deep or shallow.

Answer (score 2):

### Some secretes are too big too keep.

From an engineering standpoint, building a giant dome or continuous arc over something this big is totally doable.  You're real problem is this little caveat:

> The secrecy of the area is being actively maintained

A mega project like this takes too many people to keep secrete.  For example, the size of the Manhattan Project famously made sure that several other nations knew about it before it even got funding approval.  Likewise, if you try to make the biggest dome in the world, people will know about it before you are even done interviewing all the engineers it would take to build it.

Your first hurdle is the administrative sign-offs.  Local government will need to approve a major landscaping project like this with detailed plans, scheduled inspections, etc.  End-of-Life operations on mines and quarries are a big deal because if they are not handled properly, you risk ground water contamination and thousands of people getting sick or dying.  If your plans don't line up with what you tell local elected officials you are doing, then you risk being shut down, and it does not matter how many trillions of dollars your corporation is worth, most elected officials will not just let you poison a significant portion of thier voter base without some serious government corruption at play. This means multiple elected people, some of which are probably not already crooked have to be swayed, not just now, but for the rest of thier lives to keep this secrete.  Not to mention you'll probably have other elected people come into office while construction is still under way with no way of knowing if you can bribe them too.

Next there is the actual construction.  Something like this could take hundreds, if not thousands of workers years to complete.  The surge in workforce will also cause a surge in local housing and businesses to support the work force.  This will create all sorts of development opportunities in the area such that your construction project will cause an entire small town to suspiciously grow up around this abandoned quarry, and everyone who moves here will know why.  The effectiveness of NDAs goes way down as your number or employees goes up.

Then there is the issue of logistics.  You will need to order hundreds of thousands of tons of steel and concrete.  These are not the kinds of orders that suppliers just get an order for and fill it.  These are the kinds of orders that make them redo thier whole workflow to be able meet your demand; so, some cover story about a landfilling project will not work for your suppliers... and if they have a different cover story than your workers, then your secrete falls under scrutiny the second a supplier talks to the wrong employee.

Between the direct knowledge and gossip, there could be 10s of thousands of people who know what you are doing, and there is no way to contain a secrete that big.  All the locals will know what you have done, and a few will post YouTube videos and online articles talking about your secrete underground lair.  The very fact you tried to make it a secrete will make it just that much more clickbaity making it even more publicized than if you just did it on the up and up. I would not be surprised if millions of people know about it before you even get done making it.

### So it's better to just fill the quarry in in... mostly anyway...

One of the advantages of a mega construction project like this is that it employs a lot of different contractors from a lot of different companies, if you you hire different companies to do the same thing... then they may not notice just how much underground infrastructure you're adding to the landfill project.  A land fill project like this could include large underground reservoirs, sumps, and drainage as part of the project; so, you could have contractor team 1 come in and install a bunch of stuff, and then bury it, then contractor team 2 install the same stuff and bury it, so on and so forth.  Each organization ignorant of what is being included in each layer.

Then when you are done, you have your one last "trusted" crew install an elevator system tying them all together into a massive underground complex of hollow spaces that you can fill with all sorts of stuff and 98% of the people working on the project are none the wiser.

It will also help a lot if you have an inside man in the GSA to get you forged government classified clearance  so that you don't run afoul of local government red tape when a project inspector or city councilman shows up to ask why you're installing draining for the 6th time.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Camouflage netting on poles may do it.

The [Boeing 2](https://99percentinvisible.org/article/prop-town-fake-rooftop-suburb-hid-whole-wwii-airplane-factory/) factory of 23 acres was hidden under netting...
https://99percentinvisible.org/article/prop-town-fake-rooftop-suburb-hid-whole-wwii-airplane-factory/

In Berlin, Unter den Linden was a wide Main Street (60 m wide, 1.4 km long). This was covered with netting to deprive bombers of a recognisable target. I can't find any copyright-free photos.

The quarry could be spanned by netting to the original surface. The netting would let through rain and show, so the supports could be light.

Filling in a quarry is a big job. It might be more plausible to pretend it had just been abandoned, and flooded.

Comment: Interesting article, that looks a lot more robust than "netting", it has fake plywood houses and streets, trees and parks. And why would it appear flooded, with just netting over it?

This actually looks like a decent answer for the OP, it must be a rooftop that supports a reasonable load. I just don't understand how the Army did it...

Comment: The hard part won't be the roof., as you point out  The hard part is a surface that will pass inspection.  Your example is intended to fool aircraft flying over. It certainly would not fool somebody walking past.  I am reminded of an old sci-fi movie where they tried to hide something underground by putting up a brand new children's play area. It had the only green grass for 100's of miles.

Comment: Details are hard to come by, but this is round the corner from HollyWood. There was a building with a solid roof below it. The houses are probably light shells. There seem to be some safe routes for walking, and there are pictures of people relaxing in the sun. But a lot of it was netting, so maybe the people in the picture are actually on a cherry-picker.